# If you accidently set a very HIGH gas limit to purchase a smart contract for ETH can it be changed?

Tags: ether, gas, ethereum-wallet-dapp, gas-limit, gas-price

Ex. Gas limit was accidentally set to 5,000,000 & now when Trying to customize it keeps auto-populating to that causing me an INSANE gas fee of over $400.  I don't want to cancel because I don't want to be charged but it has been pending for 4 days & nothing I have done has worked.  Does anyone have any experience or advice on this?  TIA

Comment: You get charged only the gas that is actually being used, not the entire gas-limit that you've entered. There are generally two problems with using a high gas-limit, but none of them is about you losing ether over it. The first one is that miners pick transactions of highest gas-price lowest gas-limit first. So if you configure a very high gas-limit, then you're transaction may take a very long time to execute.

Comment: The second one is that although you don't get charged the entire amount of gas-limit, you still need your account to hold the required amount of Ether to pay for that (again - even though you won't pay more than the gas actually being used).

Comment: That makes sense. but the issue is that Since its maxed out at 5,000,000 the lowest number I can get the gas price to be is equaling $418. And I can't get the gas price low enough because it says its too low with the limit. I am just at a loss.

Comment: @CSMalls That should be a configuration option of the wallet you are using.